# How to add more than one machine to the trusted hosts list using winrm

Tags: windows, powershell, hosts, winrm

To run powershell commands on a machine from a remote machine we have to add the remote machine to the trusted hosts list of the host machine.

I am adding machine A to machine B's trusted hosts using the following command :

```
winrm set winrm/config/client ‘@{TrustedHosts="machineA"}’
```

How to add more machines say machine C, machine D to trusted hosts list of machine B?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I prefer to work with the PSDrive `WSMan:\`.

**Get TrustedHosts**

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

**Set TrustedHosts**

provide a single, comma-separated, string of computer names

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'machineA,machineB'
```

or (dangerous) a wild-card

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '*'
```

to append to the list, the `-Concatenate` parameter can be used

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'machineC' -Concatenate
```

Comment: is there a way to append hosts to the list? because I could not find any API for append.

Comment: You can append with -Value "machineB" -Concatenate

Comment: @dhcgm This solution does **NOT** work for Domain controlled Servers that rely on Kerberos for authentication. Can you please confirm ? So despite adding explicit trusted hosts I can still use non-trusted hosts to access the server as long as I have admin rights on the server. I think this works only for Workgroup Computers. Thanks.

Comment: @objectNotFound In my environment I used Powershell Remoting only on Workgroup Computers, so I cannot confirm your thesis. But I sounds plausible.

Comment: @objectNotFound Works fine for me going between domain member servers, including across domains. What it doesn't do is add permissions to the server you add it to, so if the user you're connecting with doesn't already have permission to the remote server it still won't work, but for different reasons. Once I granted the required permissions to user I was connecting with on the target server I was able to connect fine.

Answer (score 78):

```bash
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="machineA,machineB"}'
```

Comment: if anyone gets an `Error: Invalid use of command line ...` response, try removing the single quotation marks

Comment: This just doesn't work for me, single quotes or not. I get `Error: Invalid use of command` regardless.

Comment: @svarog for me it was vis-versa. I had to **add** single quotes. Before I had the same error `Error: Invalid use of command`.

Answer (score 17):

The suggested answer by [Loïc MICHEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381149/lo%C3%AFc-michel) blindly writes a new value to the TrustedHosts entry.
I believe, a better way would be to first query TrustedHosts.
As [Jeffery Hicks posted in 2010](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2010/03/30/trusted-host.aspx), first query the TrustedHosts entry:

```
PS C:\> $current=(get-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts).value
PS C:\> $current+=",testdsk23,alpha123"
PS C:\> set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –value $current
```

Answer (score 9):

I created a module to make dealing with trusted hosts slightly easier, [psTrustedHosts](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/psTrustedHosts/). You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/jasonmcboyd/psTrustedHosts) on GitHub. It provides four functions that make working with trusted hosts easy: `Add-TrustedHost`, `Clear-TrustedHost`, `Get-TrustedHost`, and `Remove-TrustedHost`. You can install the module from PowerShell Gallery with the following command:

```
Install-Module psTrustedHosts -Force
```

In your example, if you wanted to append hosts 'machineC' and 'machineD' you would simply use the following command:

```
Add-TrustedHost 'machineC','machineD'
```

To be clear, this *adds* hosts 'machineC' and 'machineD' to any hosts that already exist, it does not overwrite existing hosts.

The `Add-TrustedHost` command supports pipeline processing as well (so does the `Remove-TrustedHost` command) so you could also do the following:

```
'machineC','machineD' | Add-TrustedHost
```

Comment: @HerbM Domain names work fine. Ranges with wildcards only seem to work for a single value, i.e. you can have a comma separated list of machines, or a string containing wildcards, but not a comma separated list where one of the values in the list has a wildcard. This looks like a WinRM issue. It _will_ let you add a value with a subnet mask but it doesn't seem to interpret it as a network range when you try to connect to a machine in the range so that does not seem to work.

Comment: And apparently you have to use poor man's 'subnetting' (on octet boundaries) and not CIDR or MASK notation:

192.168.230.*
NOT:  192.168.224.0/19  # or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Altered-Ego but with txt.file:

```
Get-Content "C:\ServerList.txt"
machineA,machineB,machineC,machineD


$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\ServerList.txt"
    $currentTrustHost=(get-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts).value
    if ( ($currentTrustHost).Length -gt "0" ) {
        $currentTrustHost+= ,$ServerList
        set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –value $currentTrustHost -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    else {
        $currentTrustHost+= $ServerList
        set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –value $currentTrustHost -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

The "`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`" is required in old PS version to avoid fake error message:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   machineA,machineB,machineC,machineD
```

Answer (score 0):

`winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="ServerA"}'`

Generates this error:

`Syntax Error: input must be of the form {KEY="VALUE"[;KEY="VALUE"]}`

This worked for me (Server 2016):

`winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="ServerA"}`