# Why doesn't "Set-Item" work on Windows 7 PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install Windows 10 IoT on my Raspberry Pi 2. The PowerShell documentation tells me to put in this:

`Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value <minwinpc>`

However, when I put it into my Windows 7 PowerShell, *this* comes out:

```
At line:1 char:54
+ Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value <minwinpc>
+                                                      ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm sure they meant for `<minwinpc>` to be a place holder for the name of the computer. like it is [here](https://www.hackster.io/windowsiot/powershell-to-connect-to-a-machine-running-windows-10).

Comment: Actually, Mike, that's the exact name that it says on my Pi.

Comment: Probably without the without the angle brackets, that seems to be the [default](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpWindows10ForIoTOnYourRaspberryPi2.aspx).

Comment: For the powershell command, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548566/how-to-add-more-than-one-machine-to-the-trusted-hosts-list-using-winrm/31378248#31378248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes rather than < > around the name of the device (minwinpc)

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'minwinpc'
```