# im trying to install windows 10 IoT on my raspberry pi 3 with windows powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iot, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

so far in windows powershell ive inputed the command:
net start WinRM

now when i try to use the command:
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "minwinpc"

i get the error message of:

- Set-Item : Access is denied.
- At line:1 char:9

  - Set-Item <<<<  WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value minwinpc
  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Item], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand

im sorry, ik others have posted simmilar issues such as
[Why doesn't "Set-Item" work on Windows 7 PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928902/why-doesnt-set-item-work-on-windows-7-powershell)

but my error says: "char:9" not "char:54"

i dont realy understand much coding, but im good at following instructions! please, i need some help and THANKS!

Comment: I think we could use a little more clarification before I submit an answer officially.  Are you trying to add that system to the list of systems in Trusted Hosts?  I am assuming that's your intention, but it's better that you rephrase your question telling us what you're trying to accomplish, as opposed to a single command failure.

 To clarify the difference in "char:9" and "char:54", that's literally the character letter, on that line, in this case after "Set-Item."  In general, that points you to the 'start' of the problem it's referring to (or at least where the problem begins to show up).

Comment: well my full goal is to run .exe programs at that start up with my raspberry pi 3, with windows 10 IoT core. reason im trying the windows 10 OS is i cant seem to run .exe's with the Raspbian OS. it seems in stuck in some tutorial menu or im just not knowing what im doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your issue ("Access Denied") it seems like you're probably not launching PowerShell with administrative privileges, and may need to run `Set-WSManQuickConfig` as well.

See here for what sounds like the same issue:

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/11/23/configuring-wsman-remotely-for-multiple-computers.aspx

(from this page)

> "You should make sure to **run PowerShell with full administrative privileges** and run **Set-WSManQuickConfig** beforehand if you cannot run the commands at all because of an access denied-error."