# How to infer PowerShell Enter-PSSession arguments from an .rdp file?

Tags: powershell, remote-server, remote-desktop

I normally use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a server machine. All connection configs are saved in an `.rdp` file.

I want to instead use PowerShell to connect to that same server, in a similar fashion as SSH. I researched and found about PowerShell remoting with `Enter-PSSession`, but I don't know what arguments to give it.

What I know so far:

- Client machine OS: Windows 10. Host machine OS: Windows Server 2012 R2.
- Client and host machines are in different networks/Active Directories. Simply running `Enter-PSSession <HOSTNAME>` doesn't work.
- Host machine's PSRemoting is enabled. If I'm on a machine in its same AD, it can be connected with `Enter-PSSession <HOSTNAME>`

My question is, if I have a working `.rdp` file, can I infer what's needed to PSRemote to a remote server? Or even better, can I pass that `.rdp` file to a PS command to make the shell connection?

Comment: If the machines are in different domains, you will need to update the `TrustedHosts` property on the target system in order for it to trust the incoming connection: [How to add more than one machine to the trusted hosts list using winrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548566/how-to-add-more-than-one-machine-to-the-trusted-hosts-list-using-winrm)

Comment: Is there a trust between the domains?

Comment: @boxdog Right now `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts` seems empty. But what machine name to add to the trusted host list? I think my biggest confusion is what each computer's name is for each other.

Answer (score 0):

If trust is present, this should work.

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername <FQDN>
```

If no trust, you have to pass a PowerShell credential object. This should be a credential that has access on the target machine. The .rdp file cannot help at all.

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername <FQDN> -Credential $CustomPScredentialObject
```

You can create a credential object by:

```
$CustomPScredentialObject = Get-Credential "Domain\UserID" #this will give an interactive prompt for password
```

Non-interactive Credential Object:

```
$SecurePassword = "PlaintextPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
$CustomPScredentialObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Domain\userid", $SecurePassword
```

Now you can use this credential object for PSSession.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what <FQDN> is?
I have these fields in the .rdp file, I'm not sure if they can help determine an FQDN.
```
full address:s:SOME.ADDRESS  
gatewayhostname:s:somegthing.example.com  
workspace id:s:some.address  
use redirection server name:i:1  
loadbalanceinfo:s:tsv://MS Terminal Services Plugin.1.SOME_NAME  
```

Comment: `FQDN` is Fully Qualified Domain name. A simple google search would have answered that. When you are working with machines from other domains, `Hostname` may not be enough. You have to use `FQDN` which would be in the format `Hostname.Domainname`. Example: `Server01.Contoso.com`

Comment: For me the domain name is something like `<companyname>.local`, and `Server01.<companyname>.local` won't work for `Enter-PSSession` as a valid computername. I imagine Windows Remote Desktop connects to my server machine by first contacting the gateway host, and then get directed to the actual machine.