# Adding IP Address Range to Trusted Host in WinRM

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am trying to add a group of users into my trustedhost in WinRM configuration. It allowed me to add, but once I remove it, I am still able to access my server using my local computer.

I tried using this command

```
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="10.250.52.195/24"}'
```

I am not sure if this is working or not as I remove the trustedhosts I am still able to access my server using remote PowerShell. Wondering if anyone tried this before?

Comment: Where do you run your `winrm` command? On the server, or on the client?

Comment: `Get-Item WsMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts` You could run that to see if the list of trusted hosts and see if it worked

Comment: [How to add more than one machine to the trusted hosts list using winrm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47524518/10350118) I would check out this answer, seems like the `psTrustedHosts` module could help out

Comment: Тhe syntax for mutiple IPs if it's /24: 
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="10.250.52.*"}