# How to install Google chrome in VM using Desired state configuration (DSC) in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, dsc

I am trying the below code to install the google chrome using DSC in azure.

```
Configuration InstallGoogleChorme
{

Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'

Node installChrome
    {
        #Google Chorme
         Package Chorme
         {
         Ensure = 'Present'
         Name = 'Google Chrome'
         Path = '‪C:\Users\google\Desktop\ChromeSetup.exe'
         ProductId = ''
         Arguments = '/silent /install'
        }
    }
}



InstallGoogleChorme -OutputPath C:\

Start-DscConfiguration -Path c:\ -Wait -Verbose -Force
```

But am unable to install and got the below error.

```
The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. + CategoryInfo : NotEnabled: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x803380e4 + PSComputerName : installChrome
```

Can any one help me how to solve it/

Comment: are you doing this locally on the vm?

Comment: No i am trying this in automation DSC from azure portal.

Comment: this only works locally (since you are using `start-dscconfiguration`), so what are you doing exactly?

Comment: My requirement is to install Google chrome using DSC

Answer (score 1):

```
    # {D5D4CD98-FA01-3545-A5C2-072AC3141D12}    Google Chrome   Google LLC  116.0.5845.188  Google Chrome   
    Package "GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64" {
        Ensure    = "Present" 
        Name      = "Google Chrome"
        Path      = "\\Path-To-Installation-Source File\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi"
        ProductId = "{D5D4CD98-FA01-3545-A5C2-072AC3141D12}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the winrm listener by running "winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener" on VM.
If it's not working make sure you have winrm enable and listening over https

Comment: The command gives the response  as follows                                                                                    Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.0.0.6, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::7542:51e2:cb7c:b454%6

Comment: You only have HTTP listener and not HTTPS, try enabling HTTPS listener
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https

Ansible provides a script for this purpose and it can be used for other options as well like cred ssp etc https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

Answer (score 0):

According to that error message, you could try to add the target IP address to the `TrustedHosts` list with Powershell as admin privileges.

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'machineA,machineB'
```

Note: The command above may fail if run on Powershell

Then run the following command to view computers in the TrustedHosts list:

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548566/how-to-add-more-than-one-machine-to-the-trusted-hosts-list-using-winrm) and [this](https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0687786)